# How can I look in one worksheet and copy and paste into another workbook based off criteria from another worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

Good Morning.

I have a workbook with multiple worksheets in it. Lets say worksheet A & B

In worksheet B I have multiple supplier columns some of them have X's in them and some of them don't

What I would like to know how to do is to be if there is an "X" present in the column then look to the leftmost Column (A) and look for that part number in Worksheet A.

When it finds the part number in Worksheet A, I would like to copy all of the rows and columns associated with it and paste it into a brand new workbook.

Typically the part number is showing on multiple rows let's say rows 1-6 and the information I'd like to copy spans across multiple columns Let's say to Column "T".

Comment: @braX .... I'm completely out of my element here. I'm not sure how to even approach it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not to clear.
Assuming that you mean you have one `workbook` with a `worksheet` named A and a `worksheet` named B, the algorithm you describe is something like this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim wsA as Worksheet
Dim wsB as Worksheet
Dim suppliersRange as Range
Dim xRange as Range
Dim searchValue as string
Dim foundRange as Range

'The two worksheets in the initial book:
Set wsA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A")
Set wsB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B")

'The supplier column to search:
Set suppliersRange = wsB.Range("D:D") 'let's assume it column D for now.

Set xRange = suppliersRange.Find("X") 'Find "X"

If not xRange is nothing then 
    searchValue = wsB.Range("A" & xRange.Row).value 'Get the value from column A to do the next search
End If

Set foundRange = wsA.UsedRange.Find(searchValue) 'Search for this number that we got with the previous step.

If not foundRange is nothing then 'If it's found
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add 'Create a new workbook
    wsA.UsedRange.Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") 'And copy Sheet A in there
End If

Set foundRange = Nothing
Set xRange = Nothing
Set suppliersRange = Nothing
Set wsA = Nothing
Set wsB = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Note that since you do not specify what you mean with "multiple rows for a part" and/or what columns, etc. - I just copy the entire sheet contents. Of course you can filter out the actual range to copy, but this code for sure does the searches for you, creates the new workbook and copy-pastes from your Sheet A.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed response. I don't know if I can clarify but I will try. So when it is looking in Worksheet B for the X under a column (G:AD is the actual range of suppliers) if there is an X present in that column/row then I would like it to look to column A in the same Worksheet B with the supplier range and column A has a part number. Take that part number look in Worksheet A and then copy every single row and column that that part number is present in Worksheet A on a separate workbook.

Comment: I've slightly modified your code and ran the macro using a button. It does in fact copy some data to a new worksheet but it's not the data I need. It also brings up some sort of prompt trying to open another file.

Comment: Doesn't prompt anything here, don't know what you changed. The copy to new workbook worksheet 1, just copies the values from the usedrange of your initial worksheet A. - Again, it's a starting point that does what you described. Unfortunately, I do not KNOW what data you need or what the exact behavior should be - your question is too vague for that.

Comment: Is there a way I could email you the file for a better understanding? I would add pics but I don't have enough reputation points to do so. I think it would help clarify my end result a lot.

Comment: No there's no such way. 
You can take my answer (which does what you described), try some stuff in the editor and amend for your needs. If you get stuck at a specific point, create a new question (that has your sample code) and asks for help with a specific problem. We're not going to do your job for you. Also please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)